# How are small dtypes handled internally in xgboost?

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost

I have a dataset in a python dataframe. It is usually possible for me to reduce dtypes used from int64 to int8 to save memory. I want to train an xgboost on this data.

I have one general question: does it matter to reduce dtypes before training? (with two sub-questions: Are the data handled as small int internally? Should the calculations be performed faster ?)

Answer (score 2):

All dtypes are converted to float32 or float64 internally before training.

If you pass in a dataframe to fit, it is transformed by `pandas_transform_data()` before any training is done.

[Link to code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/2c8fa8b8b96c4c8b62a715f1334577b10512df71/python-package/xgboost/data.py#L475).

This function has four main responsibilities.

- Handling Pandas extension dtypes
- Handling nullable dtypes
- Handling sparse dtypes
- Converting to floating point.

The last part is what we're interested in. Here's the code responsible for converting to floating point.

```
    def oth_type(ser: pd.Series) -> np.ndarray:
        # The dtypes module is added in 1.25.
        npdtypes = np.lib.NumpyVersion(np.__version__) > np.lib.NumpyVersion("1.25.0")
        npdtypes = npdtypes and isinstance(
            ser.dtype,
            (
                # pylint: disable=no-member
                np.dtypes.Float32DType,  # type: ignore
                # pylint: disable=no-member
                np.dtypes.Float64DType,  # type: ignore
            ),
        )

        if npdtypes or dtype in {np.float32, np.float64}:
            array = ser.to_numpy()
        else:
            # Specifying the dtype can significantly slow down the conversion (about
            # 15% slow down for dense inplace-predict)
            array = ser.to_numpy(dtype=np.float32, na_value=np.nan)
        return _ensure_np_dtype(array, array.dtype)[0]
```

It checks if the dtype is float32 or float64. If so, it converts from a Series to a NumPy array without changing the dtype. If not, it's converted to a NumPy array with a float32 dtype.